# Extract ValueXml in Pl/Sql

Tags: oracle

I try to parse value in this xml in pl/sql.

I want to get true

hasLoanResult  value so that its 'true'

Can you help me please :( ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<hasLoanResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<hasLoanResult xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</hasLoanResult>
</hasLoanResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an [XMLQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/XMLQUERY.html):

```
select xmlquery('declare namespace soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; (: :)
    declare default element namespace "http://tempuri.org/"; (: :)
    soap:Envelope/soap:Body/hasLoanResponse/hasLoanResult/text()'
  passing <your_xml_document>
  returning content).getstringval() as result
from dual;
```

This declares the `soap` and default namespaces so it can match the relevant parts of the path. Then it extracts the text of the node you're looking for, and returns it as a string.

So with your sample document supplied in-line:

```
select xmlquery('declare namespace soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; (: :)
    declare default element namespace "http://tempuri.org/"; (: :)
    soap:Envelope/soap:Body/hasLoanResponse/hasLoanResult/text()'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<hasLoanResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<hasLoanResult xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</hasLoanResult>
</hasLoanResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>')
  returning content).getstringval() as result
from dual;

RESULT    
----------
true
```

If you have the XML in a PL/SQL variable then it's basically the same thing:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  l_xml xmltype := xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<hasLoanResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<hasLoanResult xsi:type="xsd:boolean">true</hasLoanResult>
</hasLoanResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>');

  l_result varchar2(5);
begin
  select xmlquery('declare namespace soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"; (: :)
      declare default element namespace "http://tempuri.org/"; (: :)
      soap:Envelope/soap:Body/hasLoanResponse/hasLoanResult/text()'
    passing l_xml
    returning content).getstringval()
  into l_result
  from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_result);
end;
/

true


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If your have the XML document in a CLOB or varchar2 variable then just change it to:

```
    passing xmltype(l_xml)
```

using your own variable name.